# Intellij Android Studio opens localhost page to login on github

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I am using android studio version 4.2 beta 3 and while I am using the GUI to push/fetch the studio prompts to login on github while I have already set an account.

[image]

The strange this is that I can use git on terminal but not on GUI.

I select the first option and my browser navigates me to a website that says to authorize in Github, I press the button, login on Github and then I get the following localhost page which needs some unknown credentials.

[image]

Do you have any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This actually turns out to be an Android Studio bug.
See e.g. [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174787515) and [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176138642) reports

In the corresponding IntelliJ IDEA version it is working fine.

Log in using a token instead, as a workaround.

Comment: I cannot seem to use the token either. Android Studio just stuck on loading it seems.

Comment: This is the most annoying bug and it's still not fixed!!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the issue still persists in android studios latest release but your workaround of Token works.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29792709)

Answer (score 0):

you have to Generate a new SSH key and adding it to the ssh-agent ,
you can find it [there](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

Answer (score 0):

My Github account is using the Single Sign-On from my organisation, so what worked for me was to go into Github settings -> SSH and GPG keys and then clicked on the button Configure SSO on my SSH key. Then click on "Authorize" for your organization.

Here's more details on how to do it https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/authentication/authenticating-with-saml-single-sign-on/authorizing-an-ssh-key-for-use-with-saml-single-sign-on

This works when you get the following error while checking your project out

```
  Clone failed
  ERROR: The `----' organization has enabled or enforced SAML SSO. To access
  this repository, you must use the HTTPS remote with a personal access token
  or SSH with an SSH key and passphrase
  that has been authorized for this organization. Visit
  https://docs.github.com/articles/authenticating-to-a-github-organization-with-saml-single-sign-on/ for more information.
  Could not read from remote repository.
  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
```